# python groupby and sort by specific terms and ignore the rest

Tags: python, sorting, group-by

I have an excel file that I would like to group by a specific column and sort by small to large. 
This is what data looks like.

[image: raw data]

and I would like to create a new sheet to have this result.

[image: result]

```
pp = df[['new_sku', 'Size']]
to_sort = ["Small","Medium","Large","X-Large"]
size_d = {"Small":1,"Medium":2,"Large":3,"X-Large":4}
sorted_list = sorted(to_sort, key=lambda x:size_d.get(x,0))
df['Size'] = sorted(to_sort, key=lambda x: size_d.get(x,0))


ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the input/output data in text form? So we can copy-paste it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `DataFrame`, I created sample data similar to below.

```py
df = DataFrame(
    {
        "new_sku": ["sku1", "sku1", "sku2", "sku2", "sku3", "sku3"],
        "Size": ["S", "M", "S", "M", "S", "M"],
    }
)
```

After this, ordering sample data is very simple. As you want to sort by small to large, you need to set `ascending` to `False`. If you sort by large to small, you would use `ascending=[True]`.

```py
pp = df[["new_sku", "Size"]]
pp = pp.sort_values(by=["Size"], ascending=[False])
print(pp)
```

After sorted, output would be:

```py
  new_sku Size
0    sku1    S
2    sku2    S
4    sku3    S
1    sku1    M
3    sku2    M
5    sku3    M
```